Platform Exception Error, After implementing Google Signin in Flutter with Firebase
This is my code to continue with Google.
Here is my code & also with error message, I was getting,
[implementing google providers login in flutter with firebase,googleSignIn flutter package
These are an error messages:
W/Auth    (21814): [GoogleAuthUtil] [GoogleAuthUtil] error status:UNKNOWN with method:getTokenWithDetails
I/flutter (21814): catchErrorHappened
I/flutter (21814): catchErrorHappened: PlatformException(exception, ERROR, null, null)
I/flutter (21814): PlatformException code: exception
I/flutter (21814): PlatformException message: ERROR
I/flutter (21814): PlatformException details: null

This was my code:
  Future<void> _continueWithGoogle() async {
    print("contiune with google started");
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

      if (googleUser == null) {
        print('Google sign-in canceled');
        return;
      }

      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      print('accessToken');
      print(credential.accessToken);

      UserCredential userCredential =
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      if (userCredential.user != null) {
        print('Sign in successful');
      } else {
        _showErrorMessage('Sign in failed. Please try again.');
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print("Error in continue with google");
      print("withoutError");
      print('FirebaseAuthException: ${e.message}');
      _showErrorMessage(e.message ?? 'An error occurred. Please try again.');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("catchErrorHappened");
      print("catchErrorHappened: $e");
      print('PlatformException code: ${e.code}');
      print('PlatformException message: ${e.message}');
      print('PlatformException details: ${e.details}');
      _showErrorMessage(e.message ?? 'An error occurred. Please try again.');
    }
  }


final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(scopes: ["profile", "email"]).signIn();


This is a known open issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/155429.
The current workaround is to add scopes to the GoogleSignIn class:
final googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['profile', 'email']).signIn();


i've been getting the EXACT same error, as far as i know i didn't really change anything on my code, i compared to very old commits and it doesn't seems to change at all, what i notice is that it only throws the error on physical devices, on ios and android simulators it will sign in without any problem.
Fixed: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/155429
